# How To Add Rotation In Static Map In Google Map API

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I wanna after export image from Static Map, a image will be rotated.
I searched "heading" word in doc and google but didn't find anything about this, please help me!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Google Maps Static API documentation, unfortunately there are no parameters that would allow for rotation/heading etc. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#map-parameters

Here's a longstanding feature request that would probably do what you're looking for: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821360